# Download, save to Core Data, fetch and Display? or download, display and then save?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm building an app that gets posts from a WordPress blogging site and display on a tableView. Each table view cell displays the post image, title and excerpt text. That's a course project, and use of Core Data is required. So my question is, for a better user experience, should I display the image on the cell straight after downloaded and then save to the Store or should I save to the Store, fetch, and then display?

Some considerations:

- when the app launches it will check the internet connectivity, if the connection is establish, the store will be cleaned and the latest post will be downloaded.
- It will download 5 posts at a time
- Scrolling up will perform the download of older posts.

Comment: I prefers to show at first, then save. Saving isn't cheap operation and should be executed in background queue, so we can't wait until it done.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion Akki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a opinion oriented question. The best I can do is to let you know how I design my apps to deal with this case in the past.

My solution :

1. Use `NSFetchedResultsController` to read the data from core data and use the NSFetchedResultsController's `fetchedObjects` array as a data source to your `UITableViewController` or `UICollectionViewController`
2. Implement the delegates of `NSFetchedResultsController` which will get triggered when data in Core data changes. This way u can efficiently update your `CollectionView` and `TableView` and show the data changes on UI ASAP.
3. Use Background Contexts to modify the data that way your main thread will be free and application remains responsive.
4. In order to create Background Context, I prefer parent child context architecture rather than traditional multi context architecture. parent child context architecture is easy to understand, keeps the code clean.
5. Never save image into core data. Instead save the image downloaded to document directory and save the relative link to the downloaded files in CoreData.
6. Remember I said relative path to deleted file not the absolute file. Because your application folder/sandbox path changes on killing and relaunching the app. Saving the absolute path to the file in core data is a perfect recipe to screw up the logic.
7. Don't worry about the delay in saving data to core data. The delay might be in fraction of second which you won't even notice. Saving the data in a array and then fetching the data from core data and updating array is a complete no.
8. Personally, using an array to save data instead of NSFetchedResultsController's fetchedObjects is a complete NO. why ? Simple, Array is not thread safe, because you will background thread to make web service call and parse data you might have multiple threads accessing Array simultaneously. Because Array isn't thread safe, you might easily get into state of data inconsistency and might lead to crash as well.
9. Finally use libraries like SDWebImage to efficiently load the image. SDWebImage will not only loads the images but also caches them at various levels (In RAM and HardDisk as well) there by loading images fast and swift.
10. If you are planning to use pagination to fetch data, use scrollView's delegate of `scrollViewDidScroll` to figure out when user scrolls to bottom of the table/collectionView and make web service call and fetch data in background thread update core data. As soon as you update mainObjectContext NSFetchedResults controller's delegate will be triggered and you should be able to update the UI immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your input Sandeep. So basically what you're saying is to save first and don't worry about the saving/fetching time as long I use a fetchResultsController to manage the tableView Data Source, it does sound more better structured. I liked the idea of using scrollViewDidScroll to prefetch the data.

Comment: @steven-taglohner : Yes indeed. This is how most of the apps with offline support works. Everytime ur app launches your view Controllers simply read the data from core data For your VC data source is always NSFetchedResultsController. As a result, you will always have data to show everytime user invokes your app. In a mean while u can make a call in background to fetch updated data, parse and update core data. As soon as Coredata gets updated you will get notified by delegate and ull be able to update the UI and show new data without a hassle. Most apps I have worked n seen uses this approach